# How can I decrement percentage on scroll up?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a circular progress bar in a section with id skills.

On scroll and when I arrive at this section, I increment the percentage and the color of the circle to a specific number from `data-attribute`, `data-num`.

this part of the code works very fine.

But what I want is when I go out from this section to another section up or down I want again the percentage to be 0% and the circle to be blank without any color and when I arrive again to this section this animation happens again increment the counter and the color appears again.

I tired like bellow the `if else` statement for the scrollY but I can't arrive to do it

How Can I solve that?

below I have section one, section skills, and section two

```js
const numbers = document.querySelectorAll(".number"); // get the divs 
const svgEl = document.querySelectorAll('svg circle');
const section = document.querySelector('#skills');
const counters = Array(numbers.length); // Create a counter for each div
const intervals = Array(numbers.length); // Create an intervals for each div
counters.fill(0); //Add the Value 0 for each counter

window.onscroll = function () {
    if (window.scrollY >= section.offsetTop - 50) {
        numbers.forEach((number, index) => { //Looping on each div
            intervals[index] = setInterval(() => {
                if (counters[index] === parseInt(number.dataset.num)) { //check if the counter equal to data attribut
                    clearInterval(intervals[index]);
                } else { //not equal add 1 to counter
                    counters[index] += 1;
                    number.innerHTML = counters[index] + "%";
                    svgEl[index].style.strokeDashoffset = Math.floor(472 - 440 * parseFloat(number.dataset.num / 100));
                }
            }, 20);
        });
    } else {
        numbers.forEach((number, i) => {
            intervals[i] = setInterval(() => {
                if(counters[i] === parseInt(number.dataset.num)){
                   counters[i] --;
                   number.innerHTML = counters[i] + "%";
                   svgEl[i].style.strokeDashoffset = 472;
                }
            }, 20);

        });
    }
}
```

```css
.skills-container {
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.skills .skills-container .skill-card {
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.skills .skills-container .skill-card img {
    height: 200px;
    /*filter: brightness(70%) contrast(150%) saturate(0%) brightness(150%);*/
}

.skills .skills-container .skill-card .skill-level {
    top: 70px;
    left: 50%;
}

.skills .skills-container .skill-card .skill-level .outer {
    height: 160px;
    width: 160px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    padding: 20px;
    box-shadow: 6px 6px 10px -1px rgba(0 0 0 /.15), -6px -6px 10px -1px rgba(255 255 255 / .7);
}

.skills .skills-container .skill-card .skill-level .outer .inner {
    height: 120px;
    width: 120px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: inset 4px 4px 6px -1px rgba(0 0 0/ .2),
        inset -4px -4px 6px -1px rgba(255 255 255 /.7),
        -.5px -.5px 0px rgba(255 255 255 / 1),
        .5px .5px 0px rgba(0 0 0 /.15),
        0px 12px 10px -10px rgba(0 0 0 / 0.05);
}

.skills .skills-container .skill-card .skill-level .outer .inner .number {
    font-weight: 500;
}

circle {
    fill: none;
    stroke-width: 20px;
    stroke-dasharray: 472;
    stroke-dashoffset: 472;
    transition: 2s linear;
}

svg {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.skills .skills-container .skill-card:nth-child(1) .skill-level .outer .inner .number {
    color: var(--mainColor);
}

.skills .skills-container .skill-card:nth-child(1) .skill-level circle {
    stroke: var(--mainColor);
}

.skills .skills-container .skill-card:nth-child(2) .skill-level .outer .inner .number {
    color: #4fa0ff;
}

.skills .skills-container .skill-card:nth-child(2) .skill-level circle {
    stroke: #4fa0ff;
}

.skills .skills-container .skill-card:nth-child(3) .skill-level .outer .inner .number {
    color: #ffed4f;
}

.skills .skills-container .skill-card:nth-child(3) .skill-level circle {
    stroke: #ffed4f;
}

.skills .skills-container .skill-card:nth-child(4) .skill-level .outer .inner .number {
    color: #7811f7;
}

.skills .skills-container .skill-card:nth-child(4) .skill-level circle {
    stroke: #7811f7;
}

.skills .skills-container .skill-card h2 {
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: 500;
    margin: 30px 0 20px;
    color: var(--mainColor);
}

.skills .skills-container .skill-card p {
    color: var(--secoundColor);
    line-height: 28px;
    max-width: 250px;
    margin: auto;
}

.one,
.two {
height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<section class="one"></section>
 <section class="skills position-relative" id="skills">
    <div class="container">
      <h1 class="text-center heading text-capitalize">my skills</h1>
      <div class="row skills-container justify-content-between">
        <div class="skill-card col-md-6 col-lg-4 position-relative">
  
          <div class="skill-level position-absolute">
            <div class="outer">
              <div class="inner d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
                <div class="number" data-num="95">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
           
          </div>

          <h2 class="text-uppercase text-center">html</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="skill-card col-md-6 col-lg-4 position-relative">

          <div class="skill-level position-absolute">
            <div class="outer">
              <div class="inner d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
                <div class="number" data-num="90">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
          <h2 class="text-uppercase text-center">css</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="skill-card col-md-6 col-lg-4 position-relative">
         
          <div class="skill-level position-absolute">
            <div class="outer">
              <div class="inner d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
                <div class="number" data-num="85">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
           
          </div>
          <h2 class="text-uppercase text-center">js</h2>

        </div>
        <div class="skill-card col-md-6 col-lg-4 position-relative">
       
          <div class="skill-level position-absolute">
            <div class="outer">
              <div class="inner d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
                <div class="number" data-num="90">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
          <h2 class="text-uppercase text-center">bootstrap</h2>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="two"></section>
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: Instead of using `scroll` event, maybe consider [`IntersectionObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IntersectionObserver)